# How to I create a variable for between dates

Tags: date, sas

I am struggling to create a financial year variable of interval dates.  I want variables such as 1819 (for FY 2018/19), etc.

```
data mydata;
    set mydata;
    FinYear = 9999.;
    if '01JUL2018'd <= ConductedDate <= '30JUN2019'd then FinYear=1819;
run;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?  It is not working.

Comment: Show your data, any Log Window warnings or errors and what you are getting as a result in `mydata`.  It might be that `ConductedDate` is a character variable.  You can also look into creating a custom format that maps a date range to the categorical values as in FinYear.

Comment: You need to remove the period after 9999. but your code is correct, syntax wise. Logically who knows...You actually don't say what is "not working".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing wrong, but, this is a better way to do it regardless.  Note this assumes your input variable is a numeric date variable, not a character variable - check that! If it is a character variable, you will need to INPUT it to a numeric date variable.

First we make some fake data - you should not need this step:

```
data have;
  format datevar date9.;
  do datevar = '02JAN2017'd to '01FEB2021'd by 20;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Now we use [`INTNX`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm&docsetVersion=3.2&locale=en) (time interval increment function) with the YEAR.7 interval (YEAR, but shift over by 7 - in this case, 7 months - so it is every July 1) and extract the `YEAR()` from it.  Finally we do some math to get your exact value (from the year component of that date) using the modulo (remainder) function, grabbing those last 2 digits and adding one to them.

```
data want;
  set have;
  fy_start = year(intnx('year.7',datevar,0));
  finyear = cats(mod(fy_start,100),mod(fy_start+1,100));
run;
```

I would note that I don't particularly like doing this - there are better ways, particularly using formats, to show what financial year a date value is in actually making a raw data value.

```
proc format;
  value finyr
  '01JUL2016'd - '30JUN2017'd = '1617'
  '01JUL2017'd - '30JUN2018'd = '1718'
  '01JUL2018'd - '30JUN2019'd = '1819'
  '01JUL2019'd - '30JUN2020'd = '1920'
  '01JUL2020'd - '30JUN2021'd = '2021'
  '01JUL2021'd - '30JUN2022'd = '2122'
  ;
quit;

data want;
  set have;
  format datevar finyr.;
run;
```

If you really DO need it in a value, you can always use PUT of course (`newval = put(datevar finyr.);)`

The format could be made programmatically, rather than by hand as above, using a CNTLIN dataset, to avoid having to update it every year.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to modify row 4 code as:

```
data mydata;
set mydata;
FinYear = 9999.;
if '01JUL2018'd <= ConductedDate and ConductedDate <= '30JUN2019'd then FinYear=1819;
run;
```

Thanks